# Kazhdan's property (T) for Banach algebras?

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras

A locally compact group $G$ has [Kazhdan's property (T)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan%27s_property_(T)) if the trivial representation $1_G:G\to\mathbb{C}$, $1_G(x) = 1$ for all $x\in G$, is isolated in $\hat{G}$ with the Fell topology. [Bekka](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024609306018765) took this concept from the LCG setting to the $C^*$-algebras. The snippet below with the definition of property (T) for $C^*$-algebras is taken from [Brown2006](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2006.05.003).

[image]

Brown refers to [Bekka2006](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024609306018765) for the definition of property (T) although the definitions in [Brown2006](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2006.05.003) and in [Bekka2006](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024609306018765) are not verbatim the same.

> **Question 0:** Is there a written proof in the literature (a monograph, book, or an expository text on the subject) showing that these two definitions are indeed equivalent?

---

The snippet below is from [Bekka2006](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024609306018765).

[image]

This is the first and the only instance that considers property (T) for general Banach algebras to the best of my knowledge.

> **Question 1:** Could you share the links of the literature on property (T) *(not only for $C^*$-algebras but also)* for general Banach algebras? If you know that there is none, writing this down to the comments below is also a useful input for the amateur who posed this question.

It is surprising to me that there is a vast literature for amenability for Banach algebras (which had been taken from LCG setting as well), but relatively scarce resources for property (T).