# Tracial linear functionals on an amenable Banach algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras

This post is related to [an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429556/kazhdans-property-t-for-banach-algebras) about Kazhdan property (T). The purpose of the [snippet](http://unige.ch/math/folks/jaudon/notes.pdf) below is to briefly summarize the background for the question in this post.

[image]

> **Question:** Does there exist a unital amenable Banach algebra $A$ without (nonzero) tracial linear functionals such that $Z(A,A\hat{\otimes}_\pi A) = \{0\}$ ?

Here $A\hat{\otimes}_\pi A$ is the projective tensor product of $A$ with itself,  $Z(A,E)=\{\texttt{m}\in E: a\texttt{m}=\texttt{m}a\hspace{4mm}\forall a\in A\}$ for any $A$-bimodule $E$, and $f\in A^*\backslash\{0\}$ is tracial if $f(xy-yx) = 0$ for all $x,y\in A$.